# branch main FETCH_HEAD Already up to date

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push my changes on GitHub, but it throws an error Everytime I use "git push -u origin main"

The error:

```
* branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

Comment: You seem to have merge conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You are having merge conflicts, so you need to resolve them first. Basically someone in `master` changed the same code as you did in your branch, so `git` does not know what change to keep.

So you need to decide what change to keep: The change in `master` (i.e. `foo += 1` -> `foo += 2`), the change in your branch (i.e. `foo += 1` -> `foo += 3`) or a combination of both (i.e. `foo += 1` -> `foo += 4`). There are a lot of tutorials on how to do that with git. Stackoverflow also contains many questions regarding solving merge conflicts in git, i.e. [How to resolve merge conflicts in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161813/10171966)